# Visual Studio Just-In-Time debugger, how to choose current running instance?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

When your program asserts, JIT pops up and asks you if you wish to close or debug the program.
After choosing debug, you need to confirm yes, debug.
Then, you need to choose a visual studio from the list, which is most likely the current running instance.
How do you automate this procedure?

Comment: This is not a very sensible way to debug.  Boilerplate is to press F5 in VS to start the debug/test session, no need to hack dialogs.  There is *probably* a much simpler way, but you'll have to provide background info.

Comment: My app is a plugin (.dll), which is ran by an outside app (e.g. Maya or a python script). When there's an issue, it asserts. If I want to put a break point, I use __debugbreak(). The alternative is to attach devenv to the outside app, which requires more steps.

Comment: VS has the option to start another process when you press F5.  The language matters, guessing at C++, you use Project > Properties > Debugging and modify the Command setting from $(TargetPath) to the plugin host.  You can now set breakpoints in your code as you wish.  And debugbreak() won't display a dialog.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with it, but I find it less convenient:
1. Maya takes time to load. I have a special script to load it in the background automatically when it crashes while I'm doing something else.
2. In python, I execute a big run, which I prefer to be independent from the ide. Then, for example, I can work without the ide being occupied in a debug session or the need to open a new ide instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AutoHotKey:

```
; Auto-click jit debug pop-up. Run the script as admin. 
Loop,
{
    WinWait, Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
    IfWinExist, Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
    {
        ;MsgBox, here
        WinActivate, Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger

        ; click the yes button
        SetControlDelay -1
        ControlClick, Button1

        ; choose instance from the list
        WinWait, Choose Just-In-Time Debugger
        WinActivate, Choose Just-In-Time Debugger
        ;ControlGet, lb1, Hwnd, , ListBox1
        ;msgbox, %lb1%
        ControlGet, items, List, , ListBox1
        Loop, Parse, items, `n
        {
            ;MsgBox, Item number %A_Index% is %A_LoopField%.
            IfInString, A_LoopField, administrator 
            {
                ;MsgBox, found
                Control, ChooseString, %A_LoopField%, ListBox1
                break
            }
        }

    }    
}
```

In the listbox, I'm looking for an item that contains the substring 'administrator', but you can change that.

Comment: Hi Zohar, thanks for sharing your solution about this issue. You can mark it as answer so that others with similar issue can benefit from it.